# How to Read and Write custom metadata tags into file? Node.js + Electron

Tags: node.js, file, properties, metadata, media

Good day, everyone.

I am looking to write some unique metadata into a file for indexing in my node.js app. By writing the metadata, if the file's name or location changes, I can update my database to point to the new file. What can I use to write new metadata to a file? These files are images of various formats, png, jpeg, webp, etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll just leave this for the record that 5 min in the question got downvoted without explanation and I doubt this will ever be answered. Long Life Stack Overflow...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

[ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is a perl based powerful solution for reading and writing file metadata because it is designed to handle a wide variety of file formats and standards. ExifTool is a command-line application that can extract metadata from many different file types, including images, audio, video, and documents. It supports a wide range of metadata formats, including EXIF, IPTC, XMP, and many proprietary formats used by specific software applications.

#### ExifTool with Node.js

Github: https://github.com/anasshakil/metadata

```js
import Metadata from "@enviro/metadata";

// OPTIONAL
// only required if you are using user-defined tags
async function config() {
  await Metadata.configurator({
    tags: [
      {
        name: 'CUSTOM_TAG',
        type: 'string',
        exifPropGroup: 'PDF',
        exifPropSubGroup: 'Info',
      },
    ],
  });
}


async function write() {
  try {
    const metadata = await Metadata.set("sample.pdf", {
      new: true, // returns metadata after operation
      tags: [{
        name: "CUSTOM_TAG",
        value: "Foo Bar",
      }]
    });
    console.log(metadata);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```